# git ls-files returns empty

Tags: git, github, gitlab

i am trying to find the path of a file given its filename. i tried the command

```
git ls-files --recurse-submodules -- IJob.java
```

where IJob.java is the filename.However the command returns empty.

```
[hema@localhost org.eclipse.jdt.core]$ git ls-files --recurse-submodules -- IJob.java
[hema@localhost org.eclipse.jdt.core]$
```

but the file gets listed when i simply type ls-files.

```
[hema@localhost org.eclipse.jdt.core]$ git ls-files 
.......
.......
org.eclipse.jdt.core/search/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/search/matching/VariableLocator.java
org.eclipse.jdt.core/search/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/search/matching/VariablePattern.java
org.eclipse.jdt.core/search/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/search/processing/IJob.java
org.eclipse.jdt.core/search/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/search/processing/JobManager.java
pom.xml
tests-pom/pom.xml
```

why doesnt the command list the complete path of the file.what must i include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in bash, try `git ls-files --recurse-submodules -- **/IJob.java`.

If it does not work, run `shopt globstar` to see if `globstar` is on or off. If it's off, run `shopt -s globstar` to turn it on and then the command should work.

`find . -name 'IJob.java'` should also work.